# No images to push error when container:push web in docker laravel heroku

Tags: laravel, docker, heroku

I just learned about this problem so there is a bug that has not been fixed yet. For example "**No images to push"** when running the "**heroku container:push web**" command. Please help me, thanks you so much!!!

my err:
[image]

heroku.yml:

[image]

web.dockerfile:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this?

Answer (score 0):

[Heroku provides two different methods for deploying with Docker](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker) that you're mixing up:

1. [The container registry](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime) uses the `heroku container:push` command, but not `heroku.yml`.

   If you wish to use this option, you need to rename your `web.dockerfile` to [`Dockerfile.web`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#pushing-multiple-images) (or simply `Dockerfile` if it is your only image). You should also delete `heroku.yml` since it doesn't do anything.

   Once your `Dockerfile` has been renamed, `heroku container:push` should be able to build and push your container.
2. [Building with `heroku.yml`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml) doesn't use `heroku container:push`.

   If you wish to use this version, you'll need to follow [a different set of instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#getting-started):

   1. Make sure your `heroku.yml` file is committed
   2. Tell Heroku to use the container stack:

      ```
      heroku stack:set container
      ```
   3. Deploy your code, e.g. by running `git push heroku main`

   With this flow, Heroku will build your image from your `heroku.yml` file server-side.